# How calculate the time difference for multiple timestamp values for specific groups?

Tags: php, mysql

```
+------+--------+---------------------+
| name | status | timecode            |
| U    | ON     | 2013-09-08 00:11:40 |
| A    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 00:12:29 |
| W1   | ON     | 2013-09-08 00:35:29 |
| C    | ON     | 2013-09-08 01:35:37 |
| C    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 02:12:29 |
| G2   | ON     | 2013-09-08 02:35:55 |
| C    | ON     | 2013-09-08 03:19:29 |
| J    | ON     | 2013-09-08 03:35:20 |
| W2   | ON     | 2013-09-08 04:26:31 |
| M    | ON     | 2013-09-08 04:44:23 |
| A    | ON     | 2013-09-08 05:19:29 |
| C    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 05:48:50 |
| W1   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 05:55:55 |
| M    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 06:32:29 |
| U    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 06:52:49 |
| J    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 08:12:29 |
| W2   | ON     | 2013-09-08 08:19:29 |
| G2   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 09:12:29 |
| W2   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 09:26:39 |
| Ma   | ON     | 2013-09-08 09:35:20 |
| C    | ON     | 2013-09-08 09:57:28 |
| J    | ON     | 2013-09-08 10:19:29 |
| Gw   | ON     | 2013-09-08 10:35:20 |
| A    | OFF    | 2013-09-08 11:48:50 |
| G2   | ON     | 2013-09-08 15:19:55 |
| W2   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 15:28:17 |
| G2   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 16:48:38 |
| W1   | ON     | 2013-09-08 18:10:44 |
| Gw   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 20:12:29 |
| W1   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 20:44:18 |
| Ma   | OFF    | 2013-09-08 21:12:29 |
| U    | ON     | 2013-09-08 23:15:59 |
+------+--------+---------------------+
```

Above is data from a group of sensors that go ON and OFF at different times of the day.
I would like to calculate how many hours each sensor is ON for each day.
I know how to get the difference between two times but how do I pair each ON with an OFF.
Sometimes one of the sensors may skip a reading and drop either an ON or an OFF so those will have to be discarded

Would the best option be to use temporary tables, joins or variables?
I need to print the results on a page.

Comment: chnaging database structure could help you >>  

  name | status | timecode |ontime |offtime

Comment: Q: In this case, U sensor is ON from 00:11:40 to 23:15:59? What is the expected  result for this particular sensor?

Comment: 2 `LEFT JOIN`ś  on itself, once on only the same sensor and bigger, once on the same sensor, bigger, and smaller then the 1st join. Add a where clause that your 2nd joined table should not exist (non_nullable column IS NULL) Your answer is in the second table joined. And figure out what to do with consecutive `ON` & `OFF`'s, best prepare for data-corruption.

Comment: What if a sensor skips two readings and drops an off and an on? Instead of 1.on, 1.off, 2.on 2.off you get 1.on, 2.off. With your table structure you can't catch this.

Comment: @Manjunath This data is delivered through SMS at the time of occurrence. I could create the row and then update the row when the 2nd OFF occurrence happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT x.* 
      , MIN(y.timecode) pair
      , SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(y.timecode))-TIME_TO_SEC(x.timecode)) diff
   FROM my_table x
   JOIN my_table y
     ON y.name = x.name
    AND y.status <> x.status
    AND y.timecode > x.timecode
  WHERE x.status = 'ON'
  GROUP
     BY x.name
      , x.timecode;
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry I will try this and then figure out exactly how it works.